# Problem updating apps after iOS 6 update

Tags: ios, apple-id, itunes-store

"Your account is not valid for use in the Indian store. You must switch to US store before purchasing." I am getting the above error while updating apps (I have recently installed iOS 6). My Apple ID was created with country as India. I followed the below steps:

- Open the Appstore.
- Go to Featured (scroll down to bottom until you see your Apple ID).
- Click on Apple ID.
- View Apple ID.
- Enter your Password.
- Once you login it will say your account is transferred to the respective country.

Since the store somehow thought my account was from the US, I approved "the change" to India and signed out and signed in again, still I get the same error.

Comment: As a test, try to update the apps in iTunes. This will see if it's an account problem or a phone problem.

Comment: Hi, I was able to download apps from iTunes, but not from my device. Any advice ?

Comment: Well, that, at least, means that the problem is with your device and not the account. Try going to Settings - General - Reset - Reset Network Settings. If that doesn't work, try Reset All Settings. Neither of those are destructive resets, so you won't lose your apps or data. However, if neither of those work, then I would backup to iTunes and then "Erase All Content and Settings" and then restore from iTunes. Hope one of those help!

Comment: Do you have several accounts, one for the Indian store and one for the US store?

Comment: I'm having the same issue "Your account is not valid for use in Philippines store. You must switch to Kuwait store before purchasing. I'm in Kuwait and my account also has valid Kuwait address still I get the error. This morning I got error saying m not allowed to use Saudi store. I have emailed apple support seems like they do not hv any solution for this. Even spoke to them she said the problem is in the device which cannot b as all 4 Apple product I have have this issue. Even few of my friends r havin same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to update apps because I live overseas in Japan, and after updating to iOS6 it defaulted to the Japanese AppStore. I went to the AppStore, clicked on view AppleID, then it asked for my password which was not recognized as a Japanese account, so after a few attempts, it switched me to the US store and now I can update everything.   Not sure if this will help, but following your steps helped me figure out the solution to my problem! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zrb0529's suggestion in the comments.

The problem was, I used an Apple ID 'A' when I got my iPod touch. After few months, I switched to Apple ID 'B'. Now when I installed iOS 6, it tried to download the apps with ID 'A' (which had US as the country attached to it).

After resetting the iPod touch I tried to update few apps and it showed the same error message. I deleted those apps and re-downloaded them. Now the iPod is picking Apple ID 'B' for new app downloads.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It would be nice to let Zrb post his solution as an answer and then mark that as accepted so he gets credit for the solution. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @iFriend If you register an account, you can link them and you'll get reputation for both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that, at least, means that the problem is with your device and not the account. Try going to Settings - General - Reset - Reset Network Settings. If that doesn't work, try Reset All Settings. Neither of those are destructive resets, so you won't lose your apps or data. However, if neither of those work, then I would backup to iTunes and then "Erase All Content and Settings" and then restore from iTunes. Hope one of those help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard issue to debug since you really need two devices and potentially two Apple ID to isolate whether the problem is with one of the following items:

- The Apple iTunes store is overloaded or otherwise just not working correctly and throwing bad errors at you when the problem isn't you, your device or your account.
- The network is corrupt (whether some MITM attack is going on, SSL certificates are bad, time settings on the device are causing certificate validation to fail).
- Your account is really messed up and you need to contact Apple ID/iTunes Billing support to get things remedied
- Your device needs a restore
- You are making a mistake (or made a mistake) and can correct your Apple ID store account using the self-help options as you describe.

So - if you can reach out to Apple, sometimes that is the best way to ensure your account is set up to match your expectations.

- http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/ww/

You can also do a few easy troubleshooting steps that help in most cases when the store isn't working on a particular device:

- Check the date and time on your device - perhaps let it be set automatically in the Settings app -> General -> Date & Time
- Sign out of the iTunes store from the Settings app -> Store
- [Power down the device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1430) and try again first thing after a reboot of the phone (or iPad or iPod touch)
- Potentially try and [authorize your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1420) on another device (being careful to not enable automatic downloads or [associate too many devices with your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627) in a short time)
- Potentially try another Apple ID on your device to make sure it's not in need of a wipe and a restore to factory defaults. *(which would be wise to do if two accounts fail on one device)*

Answer (score 0):

Go to featured scroll down then sign out and enter your apple id and password and it will switch you back to the store.